# Where to place the js files in Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to use [jquery-File-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) in Rails 3.2 but i am newbie and dont know where to place the required js files. Documentation says there are dirs

- app/assets: assets specific to the present application
- lib/assets: assets for libraries written by your dev team
- vendor/assets: assets from third-party vendors

I know the similar questions. But i want to know for this file upload plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the JS is specifically for that app, I would put them in `app/assets`

I tend to put anything anybody else has coded in `vendor/assets` and any reusable stuff that *I have coded* in `lib/assets.` This is things like sliders and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jquery-file-upload plugin in a rails 3.2 app. I put it in app/assets/javascript/vendor. 
You just need to add

```
//= require vendor/jquery-file-upload
```

in your application.js file

Hope this help.

Comment: there wasn't any vendor in the app/assets/javascripts
so i have created vendor folder and placed jquert-file-upload in it.
and added //= require vendor/jquery-file-upload

but its not working...
error is
    couldn't find file 'vendor/jquery-file-upload'
    (in                        C:/Sites/shoppingcart/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)

Comment: @ALi Just restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually gems/plugins are used to to handle file uploads. My favorite one, and perhaps the most ubiquitous is [Paperclip.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: yes i am using Peperclip :) but want to apply jquery plugin for progressbar

Comment: There are many file upload plugins using jquery if you want to work from this particular plugin then look at the following link here example is given
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-v4-for-Rails-3

Comment: yes i was following this link.But its not for 3.2. My problem is,                    just need to know that how i can apply this plugin on Rails 3.2 and show the form with progress bar,,  Like in the [Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)
i want to implement same thing in Ruby on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Check this app, [Upload files with jQuery File Upload and Paperclip](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)

No need to download any files, just add

`gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'`

in you Gemfile and copy paste the code shown in

`app/views/uploads/index.html.erb`

applying any necessary modifications to the model name